# Highcharts Gaussian Chart / Gaussian Distribution, with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts, gaussian, normal-distribution

I am trying to get a random array with numbers placed on a highcharts chart, in the form of a "Bell Curve". Sounds simple, but i have trouble figuring out what to use on the y axis, since the categories should be the values, or atleast i think so.

My "gaussian" function, i am aware it might not be correct, but it gives me an array which i am trying to place in a highcharts spline chart.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $array[] = rand(1, 1000);
    }

    $std = 10;
    function likelyHood($array, $std) {

        $mean = (int) round((min($array) + max($array)) / 2); 
        $standard = (max($array) - min($array)) / $std;

        for($i = 1; $i < $std/1.99; $i++) {
            $before[] = (int) round($mean - ($standard*$i));       
            $after[] = (int) round($mean + ($standard*$i));       
        } 
        $before = array_reverse($before, true);
        $result = array_merge((array)($before), (array)$mean, (array)$after);
        return $result;
    }
```

This gives me something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 199
    [3] => 298
    [4] => 397
    [5] => 496
    [6] => 595
    [7] => 694
    [8] => 793
    [9] => 892
    [10] => 991
)
```

Which i use for my X axis in my chart. Now, here is where i get kinda stuck, what can i put in my Y axis... my boss said it should have no value, and just be "Likelyhood", but highcharts want values.

I have been thinking about giving each number a 0-100 number based on their position in the array,(mean = 100, mean + 1 = 80, mean - 1 = 80, and so on)... but i am pretty sure this is a silly way to do it.

I created a Bell Curve function also, which if possible, could be used with the previously returned array, to create the Y axis, that function just takes the highest number first, and begin pushing and unshifting numbers in the array, until empty. Maybe i could change the numbers with percentage there, and have a pretty dynamic system... but...

That function is here:

```
function bellCurve($array) {

    $count = count($array);

    arsort($array);

    $max = array_slice($array, 0, 1);
    $bell = $max;
    array_shift($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $top = array_reverse(array_slice($array, 0, 2));
        array_shift($array); // istedet for array_diff($top)
        array_shift($array); // istedet for array_diff($top)
        if ($top[0] < max($bell) && $top[0] > $top[1]) {
            array_push($bell, $top[1]);
            array_unshift($bell, $top[0]);
        } else {
            array_push($bell, $top[0]);
            array_unshift($bell, $top[1]);
        }
    }
    $bell = array_filter($bell);
    return array_values($bell);
}
```

To be honest... i find this pretty difficult, and i know it might sound confusing, but i have tried alot. I dont have any problems with getting my data into my charts, i have problems understanding what exactly should be on the y axis, and if i am wrong with the x axis... that too.

An example of what i would like it to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRYde.jpg

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Unfortuantely highcharts require values, so you need calculate y and then print serie as spline type of serie.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Yeah, it is the Y axis that teases me, atm im reading a lot, trying to learn what to put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else needs a gaussian function to use with Highcharts, well here is what i came up with. It worked for me, maybe it will help someone else also. This returns the X-axis and the Y-axis.

Change Xres for amount of ticks.

```
function gaussianGraph($array) {

    $Xres = 100;

    $min = $array[0];
    $ave = $array[1];
    $max = $array[2];

    $mean = (int) round(($min + 4 * $ave + $max) / 6);  // E = (a + 4m + b) / 6
    $std = (int) round(($max - $min) / 6); // SD = (b − a) / 6

    $Xmin = $mean - 2 * $std;
    $Xmax = $mean + 2 * $std;
    $Xrel = ($Xmax - $Xmin) / $Xres;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $Xres + 1; $i++) {
        $Xindex = (int) round($Xmin + $i * $Xrel);
        $Xgaussian[] = $Xindex;
        $Ygaussian[] = (1 / ($std * sqrt(2 * pi()))) * (exp(-(pow($Xindex - $mean, 2) / (2 * pow($std, 2)))));
    }
    $result = array_combine($Xgaussian, $Ygaussian);

    return $result;
}
```